# $rootScope in angular document ready

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have this piece of code:

```
.service('webSocket', function ($rootScope, socketFactory, CONFIG, $timeout) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $rootScope.log('Waiting for connection...',CONSOLE_INFO);
    });
```

And I am getting this error:

> TypeError: $rootScope.log is not a function

This service is injected into this controller:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope, $rootScope, webSocket, myConsole ...
```

In which I have:

```
$rootScope.log = function (msg, type) { myConsole.log(msg,type); ... };
```

Can you tell me where is the problem? Or at least point me in the right direction? The reason I am using document ready function is because apart from logging messages to browser console (console.log) I use notifications for user (pNotify library) which needs to be called after DOM is loaded.

Comment: Create your `log` function in the `Angular.run` startup method.

Comment: Why don't you just use built-in angular's `$log` service or your `myConsole` service directly from your `webSocket` service?

Comment: I dont want to use $log because I have extended developer console, so just $log isnt enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing something between services using `$rootScope` should be considered generally as anti-pattern. If you don't have some different implementation of console for different controllers, you can do it Angular-way and perform all configurations in `config` block. Subscribing to document ready event in the service is also not a good idea (I would prefer to do it in `run` block), since in angular service is instantiated once it is first time required by any other service or controller or whatever. In order to have configurable service that may have different console implementation I would implement it using `provider` as follows:

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  constant('console', console).
  constant('PNotify', PNotify).
  provider('myConsole', function() {
    var log = angular.noop;
    function MyConsoleFactory() {
      return {
        log: log,
        debug: log
      }
    }
    this.setLog = function(logImplementation) {
      log = logImplementation
    }
    this.$get = [MyConsoleFactory];
  }).
  config(['myConsoleProvider', 'console', 'PNotify', function(myConsoleProvider, console, PNotify) {
    myConsoleProvider.setLog(function(msg) {
      console.log('[LOG] '+ Date.now() + ':\t' + msg);
      new PNotify({
        title: 'Title',
        text: msg
      });
    });
  }]).
  run(['myConsole', '$document', function(myConsole, $document) {
    $document.ready(function () {
      myConsole.log('Waiting for connection...');
    });
  }]);
```

In this case you don't need any controller at all.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aV9TIO07pnDs26xDBPtf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I was doing it wrong all the time. I`ll try to incorporate your suggestion into my design :)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because service code runs before service was added to controller(where `$rootScope.log` method is defined). You can move `$rootScope.log = function (msg, type) { myConsole.log(msg,type); ... };` into `app.run(...)` method and it will work.